# Apache ignite data streamer

Tags: java, stream, ignite

I have a question about the Streaming part of Ignite.

What I understand is that it is way to import data into the cache, but I also see that we can configure stream receivers to apply some other custom logic.

So I tried to create a class with the receiver and a class which injects data into the stream (so 2 main and 2 Ignite instances in server mode), but I "just" have data into the cache of the streamer (no any custom logic processed into the receiver). So, I'm asking if I missed something or if I don't well understand about what are Streams into Ignite.

If I put the sender part into the receiver, I well have the print.

Does anyone know what I am doing (or understanding) wrong?

Receiver class:

```
public class Receiver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
        CacheConfiguration<String, String> cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration<>("CacheStream");   


        igniteConfig.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfig);

        
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConfig);
        
        IgniteDataStreamer<String, String> streamer = ignite.dataStreamer("CacheStream");
        
        streamer.receiver(StreamVisitor.from((cacheLambda, e) -> {
            System.out.println("Value : " + e.getValue());
        }));
    }
}
```

Sender class:

```
public class Sender {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
        CacheConfiguration<String, String> cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration<>("CacheStream");

        igniteConfig.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfig);

        Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConfig);
        
        IgniteDataStreamer<String, String> streamer = ignite.dataStreamer("CacheStream");
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
            streamer.addData("key-"+i, "value-"+i);
        }
        streamer.flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ignite.dataStreamer("CacheStream") doesn't return same data streamer which you created before, it creates new datastreamer each time.

So, in your case, you configured 2 different datastreamers, and you upload data with streamer that doesn't have configured receiver.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It's what I was thinking about... Never mind, I will use the Messaging part. Is there an architectural reason to use Streams instead of other features? I thought that Streams was a combination of cache and compute or/and messaging, to make an abstraction layer. It could provide a kind of simple distributed orchestrator, Ignite have all it need to do that...

Comment: DataStreamer built to inject large amounts of continuous streams of data into Ignite caches. It internally will properly batch keys together and collocate those batches with nodes on which the data will be cached. But if you want to use Receiver, you can still use it, it will be invoked directly on the nodes where data will be cached.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) . I think I don't well understand the role of receiver and how they work, I'll go further into the documentation. Thank you again.